# Error BC30518 Overload resolution error because none of the 'Add' functions that are accessed with these arguments can be called..."

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio

> Error BC30518 Overload resolution error because none of the 'Add' functions that are accessed with these arguments can be called:
>
> 'Public Overloads Sub Add (addresses As String)': The value of type 'List (Of String)' cannot be converted to 'String'.
>
> 'Public Overloads Sub Add (item As MailAddress)': The value of type 'List (Of String)' cannot be converted to 'MailAddress'.

```
Public Sub sendMail(subject As String, body As String, receiverMail As List(Of String))
    Dim mailMessage As New MailMessage()
    Try
        mailMessage.From = New MailAddress(senderMail)

        For Each recipientMail As String In receiverMail
            mailMessage.To.Add(receiverMail)
        Next

        mailMessage.Subject = subject
        mailMessage.Body = body
        mailMessage.Priority = MailPriority.Normal
        smtpClient.Send(mailMessage)

    Catch ex As Exception
    Finally
        mailMessage.Dispose()
        smtpClient.Dispose()

    End Try
End Sub
```

Comment: You meant to add `recipientMail`, not `receiverMail`

Comment: This is an example of why you should use descriptive names for EVERYTHING. Those two names are too similar and not really representative of what they represent. The name of a variable of type `List(Of String)` should either be plural or end with "List". Then it would be obvious when you're using something that contains multiple items. Of course, the fact that the error message said that you were using a `List(Of String)` where a `String` was expected should have been a clue.

Comment: Further to what I said, you could use `receiverMailAddresses` and `receiverMailAddress` for the two variables. It makes sense that the loop control variable is the singular form of the list name.  When you see the two in an Intellisense list, it's then obvious which one you need because they clearly mean different things, where `receiverMail` and `recipientMail` actually mean the same thing so it's hard to know which one represents which thing.

Comment: thanks. Raymond chen's answer solved my question!

Comment: You can figure this out yourself by reading the error message. It says that there is an `Add` method that takes a `String`, but you passed `List(Of String)`. And there is also an `Add` method that takes a `MailAddress`, but you passed `List(Of String)`. So either you really meant to pass a `List(Of String)` and you need to find some way to add an entire list, or you meant to pass a `String` or `MailAddress`.